# To what extent can a teacher be disciplined for what they put on social media?

Tags: professionalism, united-kingdom, discipline

So this recently happened to a friend of mine who is a teacher.

He uses twitter a lot. He has a separate account for work which uses a fake name, on this account he vents about work and generally uses twitter as you would. He never refers to people by their real names or to the school so things cant be linked back to his school. It just so happens that a few people who know him from work follow him on twitter so those people alone know what he is talking about.

Recently he tweeted that he disagreed with a method a teacher used in a lesson, and also that he didn't think they like him blah blah vent vent vent.

Anyways long story short these tweets have been printed off by the teacher he was referring to (who just so happens to be high up in the teaching ranks). This teacher basically told him that he had offended her and that he could be disciplined for what he put. It went all the way to the head of the school who said it could be taken further and that the tweets were "going in a file".

Is this justified?

I completely understand if he had slandered the school or the teacher by name (he didnt). He was merely using social media as an outlet for his own frustrations?

I would not have thought this was punishable am I wrong?

Since then he has deleted all his tweets, made his account private and is absolutely devastated that this has happened.

Is the school in the right here?
(No I am not the friend:-) )

EDIT:
So I appreciate the answers but there appears to be some confusion.

1. The tweets in question were not slanderous in any way. They were tweets about his own opinion on a correct method of teaching a class
2. He understood his account was public for all to see

It just seems unjust to punish someone for publicly vocalizing their opinions, it looks like what he says was taken completely out of context.

Comment: Legal question. Depends on exactly where you are, what contract you have signed, and what that employer's policies are, whether you are in academia or industry. In general, freedom of speech includes freedom for others to react to what you have said; unconsidered words may have unintended consequences. Badmouthing your employer or co-workers should not be posted in public or under your own name, and probably should not be posted at all since online anonymity is often easily pierced. The school may or may not be in the right, but your friend is in the wrong.

Comment: You should add a Country tag. I posted an answer, but could not say much about job protection since it can be extremely different depending on the country.

Comment: @Keshlam "Badmouthing" is probably too strong a term to use about what he wrote. His issues where the disagreements he had with a method of teaching. It just seems like he's being punished for not agreeing with the school

Comment: I would suggest telling your friend to keep ALL negative comments out of ALL social media forums.

Comment: Does the offended party have something that conclusively connects those tweets to your friend, or did she just assume that because the tweets criticize X and she does X, she's the only person in the entire UK that does it and therefore it must be directed at her?  Or is this one of those cases where the mutual followers kind of give it away?

Comment: "so those people alone know what he is talking about." This clearly isn't true as the offended person worked it out. If they did, lots of other people probably have as well.

Comment: @PhilipKendall those people alone include ex-colleagues of said offended person

Comment: I am not sure I understand the point of using a fake name for the purpose of keeping personal and work life separate, and then letting your colleagues know the fake name.

Comment: @MaskedMan - Especially when the fake name's account is followed by (presumably) people without fake names.  It's really easy on Twitter to see who someone is following.  "Oh, one of my fellow teachers is following this odd-named account who's tweeting about something very familiar...."

Comment: "things cant be linked back to his school" Obviously they can, or this wouldn't be an issue. Key principle learned here, again: keep your work and personal stuff apart and don't mix them. Telling collegues his private/anonymous twitter handle was a clear breach of the work/private barrier.

Comment: An fyi my friend is very good at his Job and its a shame this has happened. The purpose of keeping his account anonymous was so PARENTS couldnt link it back to the school. He clearly never thought his colleagues would be taking issues with him

Answer (score 10):

*Freedom of speech does not mean absence of consequences.*

The first consequence is, he now has a bad relationship with another teacher in the school, for personal reasons. This might weigh on his career, whether it is fair or not does not change it. People might start talking behind his back, and this will definitely damage his reputation.

A teacher holds a representation role. He has to be an example, even in his private life. What he said or wrote might not be held against him in a legal sense, but it can be remembered.

*Can he be disciplined ?*

There is a legal question here : he needs to read his contract carefully again and check the clauses about representation and opinions. He should also read the internal rules for "good behaviour", if applicable. He could have a meeting with a higher-up in the school who is going to ask him, basically, *"would you please refrain from talking about work on social media ?"*, but they cannot force him to stop talking.

*Employment consequences ?*

Depending on the country, however, the school board could be seized and his behaviour could be judged "inadequate" (or something along these lines). In some countries where job protection is low, he might get fired basically for little to no reason. On the other hand, some countries (France for instance) have high job protection for teachers, so he would be totally fine.

Comment: This is so true "Freedom of speech does not mean absence of consequences."  I repeat this line to my kids all the time.

Comment: Thank you this clears some things up that were confusing me

Answer (score 7):

> "Is this justified"

Of course it is. Talking badly about your workplace and colleagues in public is extremely unprofessional and, quite frankly, it's also not very smart. It shows a significant lack of judgement and personal integrity.

Some basic rules

1. If you have issues at work, try to resolve them constructively with the specific people at work. If it can't be addressed make your peace with it or move on.
2. Never say anything in public about someone else, that you wouldn't be willing to say directly to their face
3. Don't assume that there is any type of "privacy" on social media or any other online activity. Same goes for party, bars, etc.

Comment: Another awesome rule to live by "Never say anything in public about someone else, that you wouldn't be willing to say directly to their face".

Comment: Kids these days seem to think that privacy was a quaint 20th century concept that lasted from when communities became too large for everyone to know everyone else's secrets until technology caught up with that. They are probably right.

Comment: Is it okay to write negative comments about people on social media if I am okay with saying the same thing to their face? SE's so-called "Be Nice" policy also has a similar flaw.

Comment: @MaskedMan it is okay if you can live with consequences of what you said.

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is just don't do it anymore.

There was a case where a guy that just worked maintenance for a sports team and he posted a trade was stupid.  It was in the contract could not publicly bad mouth the team or management, he got fired, and it held up in court.

Answer (score 1):

## Apologise and attempt to move on

A lot can be (and has been) on the rights/wrongs, but this has happened now, so we need to move forwards from here.

He's been found out, so has to accept the consequences and not try to duck out of anything.

As with any other case of doing something wrong and being found out, be gracious in apologies and stay clean in future.

Treat it as a lesson learnt.

Answer (score -4):

> Is the school in the right here?

Absolutely. The school received a complaint from one colleague about an other, at minimum they have to investigate.

> Is the colleague being an unreasonable cry-baby?

Absolutely. They could've spoken with your friend privately, find some common ground, maybe learn something in the process. If I'm to take you at your word that your friend has been perfectly civil while venting<sup>1</sup>, it's obvious the colleague emotionally invested in their teaching style so much that they won't take constructive criticism.

<sup>1</sup> It's hard to believe the worst thing your friend posted was a variation on *my colleague doesn't like me*. If he made personal remarks, the colleague is well justified in taking offense - and escalating. Add that to the  criticism I mentioned above and it doesn't seem so "constructive" any more.

> Is your friend in the wrong?

Absolutely. If you must shitpost, remain anonymous. He brought this on himself.

Comment: Downvoters, feedback please?

Comment: I downvoted this because it really sounds like jumping on the bandwagon of scolding the OP. I didn't learn anything from reading this answer. You are extremely conjectural about the colleague's emotional poise and once you remove that from the equation there's no justification for your opinion in this answer.

Comment: @djechlin Not scolding the OP but can't avoid not scolding the friend... he should've known better. I've stated my assumptions regarding the offending content - but these are probably wrong. Will edit with counter-point.